# Spring Boot Hibernate shows different behavior in different OSs. Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am stuck in a very strange problem. I have two Ubuntu 22.04.4 servers and I have a Spring Boot application which I want to run on those servers on a docker environment.

The Application is generated by Jhipster 8.1.0 nad has:

- `<java.version>17</java.version>`
- `<spring-boot.version>3.2.0</spring-boot.version>`
- `<hibernate.version>6.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>`
- `<liquibase.version>4.24.0</liquibase.version>`
- `<validation-api.version>3.0.2</validation-api.version>`
- `<hibernate-annotations.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate-annotations.version>`
- `<hibernate-types.version>2.21.1</hibernate-types.version>`

You can see the entire `pom.xml` at the end of questation.

The application runs commpletly ok on my local machine which is also an Ubuntu.

My both servers have same configuration.

- Docker version is 25.0.3
- Java version is 17.0.9
- maven version is 3.2.5

On one server application runs without a problem but on other server I encounter an strange error:

```
2024-02-17T10:13:36.691Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION
2024-02-17T10:13:36.754Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-17T10:13:36.778Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:936)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
        at tech.siloxa.subinja.SubinjaApp.main(SubinjaApp.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.spi.PhysicalConnectionHandlingMode.<clinit>(PhysicalConnectionHandlingMode.java:50)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.buildJpaPropertyMap(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:162)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.getJpaPropertyMap(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:132)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

I looked up in internet and all solutions were about version of jpa and hbernate. But I checked my own and see no problem and it can not be about versions because on my local and one of the servers every thing is ok. I have absolutly no idea what I can do.

Please Help me!

`pom.xml` :

```xml
    <properties>
        <!--
            Build properties
            The spring-boot version should match the one managed by https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version}
        -->
        <maven.version>3.2.5</maven.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>tech.siloxa.myprofc.MyProFcApp</start-class>
        <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx1G</argLine>
        <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
        <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
        <jhipster-dependencies.version>8.1.0</jhipster-dependencies.version>
        <spring-boot.version>3.2.0</spring-boot.version>
        <archunit-junit5.version>1.2.1</archunit-junit5.version>
        <checkstyle.version>10.12.5</checkstyle.version>
        <git-commit-id-maven-plugin.version>7.0.0</git-commit-id-maven-plugin.version>
        <hibernate.version>6.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.11</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <jaxb-runtime.version>4.0.4</jaxb-runtime.version>
        <jib-maven-plugin.architecture>amd64</jib-maven-plugin.architecture>
        <jib-maven-plugin.image>eclipse-temurin:17-jre-focal</jib-maven-plugin.image>
        <jib-maven-plugin.version>3.4.0</jib-maven-plugin.version>
        <lifecycle-mapping.version>1.0.0</lifecycle-mapping.version>
        <liquibase-plugin.password/>
        <liquibase-plugin.url/>
        <liquibase-plugin.username/>
        <liquibase.version>4.24.0</liquibase.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.3.1</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.3.2</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.1</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.4.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <maven-idea-plugin.version>2.2.1</maven-idea-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.6.3</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.3.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <maven-site-plugin.version>3.12.1</maven-site-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>3.4.0</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <modernizer-maven-plugin.version>2.7.0</modernizer-maven-plugin.version>
        <nohttp-checkstyle.version>0.0.11</nohttp-checkstyle.version>
        <profile.api-docs/>
        <profile.e2e/>
        <profile.no-liquibase/>
        <profile.test/>
        <profile.tls/>
        <properties-maven-plugin.version>1.2.1</properties-maven-plugin.version>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.10.0.2594</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <spotless-maven-plugin.version>2.41.1</spotless-maven-plugin.version>
        <validation-api.version>3.0.2</validation-api.version>
        <hibernate-annotations.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate-annotations.version>
        <hibernate-types.version>2.21.1</hibernate-types.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.30</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
                <artifactId>jhipster-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${jhipster-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit-junit5-api</artifactId>
            <version>${archunit-junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Adding the engine dependency to the surefire-plugin unfortunately does not work in the current version. -->
            <!-- https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_junit_5 -->
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit-junit5-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${archunit-junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-60</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```